# Implementing a Pipe in C# - which (stream?) classes to use?

Tags: c#, stream, pipe

I am having some hard time understanding how to work with streams in C#.

I plan to have a class of this form:

```
class Pipe {
    public void PutChar(char c) { ... }
    public char GetChar() { ... }
}
```

The idea is that one thread will put chars in this `Pipe` through its `PutChar()` method, and later on other thread will make use of `GetChar()` to get the chars that are in `Pipe`.

In Java I'd make use of `PipedReader` and `PipedWriter` classes. There seem to be no equivalent classes in C#, so which (stream?) classes should I use here? Or aren't streams the correct way of implementing this? Maybe I'd be better off using a `Queue`, instead?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not clear if you are looking for the specific named pipes OS implementation, as answered by others. Perhaps you are looking at pipes in a generic sense? I

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you want to communicate across threads and you don't want to use any NamedPipes as mentioned in above answers than

1- You can create Producer Consumer Queue.

2- If you are using .net 4.0 than [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) can be used.

Answer (score 1):

Look in the [System.IO.Pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298714.aspx) namespace for classes that can stream to pipes. However, you may want to consider [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456779.aspx) using [NetNamedPipeBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netnamedpipebinding.aspx) for implementing pipes in your application.

Comment: That seems way "heavier" than what I pretend. I just want a way to communicate across threads, not across processes.

Comment: Why do you need to communicate across threads? Is one thread a worker of some sort?

Comment: Yes, the "left" thread is a producer and the "right" one is a consumer.

Comment: Unless you specifically need to control the worker thread, just queue operations with the ThreadPool class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx. You can do `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(SomeMethod);` or `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(obj => { Console.WriteLine(obj); });` as examples.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .NET 4.0 take a look at the BlockingCollection and the Task Parallel Library. Those two put together create a great way to move data across threads using Tasks.

[Example code on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) shows everything you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [NamedPipe's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365783(v=vs.85).aspx).  Also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719353/win32-named-pipes-and-remote-clients) post.

Comment: I don't want IPC. I don't want named pipes.

Answer (score -1):

StreamReader & StreamWriter are very similar to PipedReader & PipedWriter. If you declare a MemoryStream to hold the buffer you can implement it.

A quick code sample is below which may do what you are looking for.

```
class Pipe {
    MemoryStream _ms;
    StreamReader _sr;
    StreamWriter _sw;

    public Pipe()
    {
       _ms = new MemoryStream();
       _sr = new StreamReader(_ms);
       _sw = new StreamWriter(_ms);
    }

    public void PutChar(char c) { _sw.Write(c) }
    public char GetChar() { return _sw.Read();  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you mean _sr.Read() ? Either way it doesn't seem to work :( Tried adding some data to the Pipe and then using GetChar() to get it and all I see are -1's.

Comment: how is you instantiating and calling the methods? Are you making sure your threads uses the same instance of the Pipe class?

Comment: I think the MemoryStream only maintains one current position, not separate ones for read and write.