# SMB named pipe with no connection restrictions

Tags: c++, winapi, named-pipes, smb

I am trying to get a windows 10 VM to connect over SMB to another windows 10 VM. I am trying to create a named pipe on VM1 that will allow anyone to connect to it with all permissions. I am then trying to connect VM2 to that named pipe.

Currently i am getting some errors over wireshark when trying to make the connection. Below is my server, client, and wireshark errors.

*With both the server and client running on the same VM, the connection works fine and i get the message on the server as expected.*

**What is the simplest way to create an SMB named pipe on VM1 and have VM2 connect to it? Have i over complicated it?**

---

**Running accesschk on my named pipe** gives this result, which shows read/write to everyone.

```
Accesschk v6.12 - Reports effective permissions for securable objects
Copyright (C) 2006-2017 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

\\.\Pipe\MyTestPipe
  RW Everyone
```

---

**Wireshark Output** with filter `tcp.port==445`

```
No. Time    Source  Destination Protocol    Length  Info
67  13.039161   fe80::d0ab:b3ed:8e74:a86c   fe80::8998:c1e0:9490:26f4   TCP 86  52601 → 445 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64800 Len=0 MSS=1440 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
68  13.039260   fe80::8998:c1e0:9490:26f4   fe80::d0ab:b3ed:8e74:a86c   TCP 86  445 → 52601 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1440 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
69  13.039659   fe80::d0ab:b3ed:8e74:a86c   fe80::8998:c1e0:9490:26f4   TCP 74  52601 → 445 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=2108160 Len=0
70  13.039817   fe80::d0ab:b3ed:8e74:a86c   fe80::8998:c1e0:9490:26f4   SMB 147 Negotiate Protocol Request
71  13.040240   fe80::8998:c1e0:9490:26f4   fe80::d0ab:b3ed:8e74:a86c   SMB2    526 Negotiate Protocol Response
72  13.040755   fe80::d0ab:b3ed:8e74:a86c   fe80::8998:c1e0:9490:26f4   SMB2    252 Negotiate Protocol Request
73  13.041052   fe80::8998:c1e0:9490:26f4   fe80::d0ab:b3ed:8e74:a86c   SMB2    586 Negotiate Protocol Response
74  13.042232   fe80::d0ab:b3ed:8e74:a86c   fe80::8998:c1e0:9490:26f4   SMB2    240 Session Setup Request, NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE
75  13.042386   fe80::8998:c1e0:9490:26f4   fe80::d0ab:b3ed:8e74:a86c   SMB2    410 Session Setup Response, Error: STATUS_MORE_PROCESSING_REQUIRED, NTLMSSP_CHALLENGE
76  13.042954   fe80::d0ab:b3ed:8e74:a86c   fe80::8998:c1e0:9490:26f4   SMB2    717 Session Setup Request, NTLMSSP_AUTH, User: WINDEV1905EVAL2\User
77  13.043497   fe80::8998:c1e0:9490:26f4   fe80::d0ab:b3ed:8e74:a86c   SMB2    150 Session Setup Response, Error: STATUS_ACCOUNT_RESTRICTION
78  13.043828   fe80::d0ab:b3ed:8e74:a86c   fe80::8998:c1e0:9490:26f4   TCP 74  52601 → 445 [RST, ACK] Seq=1061 Ack=1377 Win=0 Len=0
```

---

**SMB Server C++**

Build with Developer Command Prompt > cl /EHsc smb-server-prototype.cpp /link AdvAPI32.Lib

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)

{
    HANDLE hPipe;
    char buffer[1024];
    DWORD dwRead;

    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
    ZeroMemory(&sa, sizeof(sa));
    sa.nLength = sizeof(sa);
    sa.bInheritHandle = false;
    bool bInitOk = false;
    bool bSetOk = false;
    SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR SD;

    bInitOk = InitializeSecurityDescriptor(&SD, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION);

    if (bInitOk) {
        bSetOk = SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(&SD, TRUE, (PACL)NULL, FALSE);
        if (bSetOk) {

            sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = &SD;

            hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\MyTestPipe"),
                PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
                PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE | PIPE_WAIT,
                PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,
                1024 * 1024,
                1024 * 1024,
                NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT,
                &sa);
            while (hPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            {
                if (ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL) != FALSE)   // wait for someone to connect to the pipe
                {
                    while (ReadFile(hPipe, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, &dwRead, NULL) != FALSE)
                    {
                        /* add terminating zero */
                        buffer[dwRead] = '\0';

                        /* do something with data in buffer */
                        printf("%s", buffer);
                    }
                }

                DisconnectNamedPipe(hPipe);
            }
        }
    }



    return 0;
}
```

---

**SMB Client C++**

Build with Developer Command Prompt > cl /EHsc smb-client-prototype.cpp /link AdvAPI32.Lib

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    HANDLE hPipe;
    DWORD dwWritten;


    hPipe = CreateFile(TEXT("\\\\WINDEV1905EVAL\\pipe\\MyTestPipe"), //WINDEV1905EVAL is the name of the VM serving the named pipe
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        0,
        NULL);
    if (hPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        WriteFile(hPipe,
            "Hello Pipe\n",
            12,   // = length of string + terminating '\0' !!!
            &dwWritten,
            NULL);

        CloseHandle(hPipe);
    }

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you need help with setting up your network, rather than with actual code. [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) is the place to ask those questions.

Comment: you need call `NetUseAdd` in client for "\\\\WINDEV1905EVAL\\IPC$" - set user name/password in `USE_INFO_2` before connect

Comment: @RbMm I am asking for any user to be authenticated with all permissions. Not a specific user and password. Just need it to work with all to test for now.

Comment: i think if you call `GetLastError()` in client after create file fail - you got `ERROR_LOGON_TYPE_NOT_GRANTED` ( *A user has requested a type of logon (e.g., interactive or network) that has not been granted. An administrator has control over who may logon interactively and through the network.*)

Comment: you need allow allow Anonymous logon

Comment: @RbMm how do i enable the anonymous login, just to check and see if that is the issue? I can't find a way to do that. Windows 10.

Comment: Please check if these settings could help: [Restrict anonymous access to Named Pipes and Shares](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/network-access-restrict-anonymous-access-to-named-pipes-and-shares) and [Named Pipes that can be accessed anonymously](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/network-access-named-pipes-that-can-be-accessed-anonymously)

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT I have read through both of those several times already, but can't find anywhere in that how to change these settings. They mention a location `Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options`, but i can't find that anywhere.

Comment: open the "Local Security Policy", then find them under Security Settings > Local Policies > Security Options

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT thank you. However, changing both those settings did not help. Still getting the same issue.

Comment: Please check this link from @brian could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/719397/10611792

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured out the issue. The VM hosting the named pipe, needed to have `file and print sharing` turned on. After turning that on, everything started working.